# Should I need a callback or promise in a for loop while inserting bulk data

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, mongoose, promise

I have an xls with a million rows and I am inserting into MongoDB through Node.js, this is the code I am trying,

```
var TR  = require('../models/tr');

var obj = xlsx.parse(__dirname + '/TD.xlsx'); // parses a file
var xl = obj[0]['data']



     for(var i=0; i< xl.length; i++) {
        var row = (xl[i])
        var doc_no = row[0]

            tr.doc_no = doc_no
            tr.save(function (err) {
                  if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
                  res.send('saved');

                  // saved!
                });



     }
```

So far when I tested with around 100 records it looks fine, will it work with million records? I am afraid because as the nature of for loop is asynchronous, will be mess the records inserted?

Comment: Are you sure it's working with 100 records? Variables declared with `var` do not have block scope.

Comment: I think you are right,it is isn't coming correctly, too inconsistent, can you kindly give me a hint or is the promise/callback the only options here?

Comment: I could improve the code for you but it wouldn't necessarily work with 1,000,000 records.That's something you would need to find out through experimentation.

Comment: I have edited the code, can you please just tell me how to make the for wait until a record is saved, so it can run synchronously? I will split the records into multiple smaller chunks though...

Comment: I doubt this is working. You are sending a response as soon as the first save finishes, not after all of them did.